# Can I register domain names with a unique extension in Ethereum Name System once and never pay for renewal?

Tags: domain-registration

Several months ago in an interview with Vitalik Buterin I heard that you can register a domain name in Ethereum Name System (ENS) once and hold it as long as you want without being dependent on a registrar. I then searched the ENS [site](https://ens.domains/) a bit and found that they were offering .zil and .crypto domain registration for 25$. Now they seem to offer only the registration of .eth domains which will be required to renew.

Can I register domain names with a unique extension (not .eth) in Ethereum Name System once and hold them as long as I want without paying for renewal? The extension is unique and not present in any extension lists offered by other traditional registrars.

Can I connect a domain name registered in Ethereum Name System to any hosting rather than uploading the website to IPFS? As in ENS it is required to "upload your website to IPFS"  which is a "peer-to-peer network for storing and sharing data in a distributed file system" and the advantages of a distributed website storage and serving over centralized storage are unclear.

Comment: I dont have the knowledge to answer authoratively, but while it may be possible to register in etherium, it is unlikely in the extreme that this registration would be recognised by IANA who co-ordinate/control the root nameservers - ie are the defacto deciders of whi gets tld's.  Its certainly possible for other groups to attempt to take this mantle, but even in the old days when it would have been easier they never succeeded.  It may be etherium can create their own ecosystem but its unlikely to be accepted as authorative on the wider internet.

Comment: I supposed that it's possible to create a domain name with any other extension on ENS (from the "front-end" it should not matter where and how the domain was registered). Yet, according to HN [link](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27673223), it seems too much hustle required for this, as the ENS domain names should be resolved via .link extension in cloudfare etc.